# declaring a function javascript alike in php?

Tags: php

how can you declare a function like this in php?

```
class Test {
    function __construct(){
        $this->method = function($var){ // <-- declaring a function javascript alike
            echo $var;
        };
    }

    function func(){
        if($this->method){
            $this->method('test');
        }
    }
}

$Test = new Test();
$Test->func();
```

Comment: It depends on which PHP version you are using. Which is it?

Comment: in 5.3 see: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: What are you trying to do? I don't recommend using this, because of compatibility issues. There's a hideous way to make it compatible though... `create_function()`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it just like that.  Simply put a `public $method;` in your class.

Unless you have a specific reason, defining functions in variables is poor practice, as it can be difficult to debug.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that since PHP 5.3, which introduces anonymous functions (closures). See the [manual explaing them](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.3: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php
PHP 5.2 (Ugly solution): http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php

By the way, I see no reason to use anonymous functions in Your code. Just make that function protected method.

Comment: what do you mean by a anonymous function?